# How do I indicate that two variables are equal to each other

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let's say I have the function `x + y = z` and I know that `x = y`. How can I indicate this in Mathematica?

I tried using

```
x + y == z x == z
```

---

I have a formula `(x1 + x2)/2 = k` and I'm given the information that `x1 = x2 = 2`. Is there anyway to indicate this in Mathematica?

Comment: Can you explain in full what you are trying to achieve? Your question based on the assumption that it is possible to 'define' such a thing in general. It is not. Some context is necessary to answer the question.

Comment: this looks like XY question. `in which the real issue, X, of the person asking for help is obscured, because instead of asking directly about issue X, they ask how to solve a secondary issue, Y, which they believe will allow them to resolve issue X.`

Comment: If you know that x == y, then use the replacement rule `y -> x`, e.g., `x + y == z  /.  y -> x`. If you want the substitution to always be made, use `Set`, i.e., `y = x`.

Answer (score 2):

As for your 2nd question, using [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) is one approach that can be used. Like so:

```
Simplify[(x1 + x2)/2 == k, x1 == x2 == 2]
```

> ```
> k == 2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is essentially a rewrite engine that also knows math. Like u + u = 2u. Also, Set (=) and Equal (==) are completely different concepts. Truly understanding the three liner below helps in moving forward with Mathematica.

```
equation = x + y == z
rule = x -> y
equation /. rule
```

[image: Output here]